# Jquery 2.0 mouseenter is not working for the new elements

Tags: jquery

Hi i am trying to add event on newly added element but it is not working for me. Please tell me the issue.

```
<div class='btn'>Button</div>

<script>
$('.btn').on({
 click: function(){
   $(".btn:last").after("<div class='btn'>Button</div>"); //adding new element
},
mouseenter: function(){
 console.log("in");
},
mouseleave: function(){
  console.log("out");
}
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8kSMe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event delagation...

If you use `.on()` properly, it work:

```
$(document).on({
  click: function(){
      $(".btn:last").after("<div class='btn'>Button</div>");
  },
  mouseenter: function(){
    console.log("in");
  },
  mouseleave: function(){
     console.log("out");
  }
}, '.btn');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8kSMe/1/

Using `.on()` the way you used is like using `$('.btn').click()` wich is good for static elements. But when your targets are dynamicly added, you need to target the closest static parent (in this case `document`) and the pass the dynamic selector (`.btn`).

I guest jQuery can explain it better than me. Go check the section **Direct and delegated events** in the [jQuery .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) information page.

Comment: hi, thanks :) .. your code is working fine, plz explain this code. I also used .on() but it was not working.

Comment: @MohammadShahid Added a little explaination.